# How can you tell if an an ASP.NET request is remote or from localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How can you programmatically determine if an an ASP.NET request is remote or from the localhost?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found it: [`HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Request.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

Comment: Which can be spoofed. And not reliable if the host has multiple nics.

Comment: It can't be spoofed. It's no less reliable than Request.IsLocal (in fact, if you look in Reflector, IsLocal is implemented in terms of UserHostAddress!)

Answer (score 0):

yes HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal will must works. I am also using it in one of my project and working fine.